# Serializing list of nullable CDATA

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I am trying to deserialize a XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Foos xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <FooList>
    <Foo>
      <Bar>bar value</Bar>
      <Stack />
    </Foo>
    <Foo>
      <Bar>bar value</Bar>
      <Stack><![CDATA[This is some cdata, where <br> html code is left as is..]]></Stack>
    </Foo>
  </FooList>
</Foos>
```

Into the following class

```
[XmlRoot("Foos")]
public class Foos
{
    [XmlArray("FooList")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Foo")]
    public List<Foo> FooList { get; set; }
}

public class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Stack", typeof(XmlCDataSection))]
    public XmlCDataSection Stack {get; set; }
}
```

The problem is, that the resulting `FooList` of `Foos` only contains one (1) element, which is the first `Foo` block, with the `Slack` property set to null. If i add a CDATA value to `stack`, like with the second `Foo` block, then i will end up with a list of both elements.

For some reason, the deserialization stops, after reaching a CDATA value which is null.

I have tried creating a private string and creating the setter and getter of `Stack`, such that is uses the private property to store the CDATA string. This doesn't change anything.

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: Why does `Stack` need to be an `XmlCDataSection` and not just a `string`, though? That the element data happens to be CDATA-escaped markup is a detail of the representation. What if it read `<Stack>This is some cdata, where &lt;br&gt; html code is left as is...</Stack>`, would you want to reject that since it's not CDATA? (Also, this is about *de*serialization, not serialization.)

Comment: Regarding deserialization, then you are completely right. I have changed the words, in the question. The problem regadring the CDATA entry is, that i cannot change the data and/or the format. I have to deserialize the data as is.

Comment: Just use `public string Stack { get; set; }` without any attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Get to a cdata section through a string. Object model:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("Foos", Namespace="", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class Foos {
    [XmlArrayItem ("Foo", IsNullable=false)] public Foo[] FooList { get; set; } }

[Serializable] public partial class Foo {
    public string Bar { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore] public string Stack { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Stack", IsNullable=true)] 
    public XmlCDataSection StackCDATA {
      get { return new XmlDocument().CreateCDataSection(Stack ?? String.Empty); }
      set {
        Stack = value == null 
          ? String.Empty
          : ( String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value.Value)
            ? String.Empty
            : value.Value); } }

    public override string ToString() { return String.Format("Bar:{0} Stack:{1}", Bar, Stack); } }
```

The right way to specify a null element is `<Stack xsi:nil='true' />`. With this addition, your deserialization will be flawless. However, on the first occurrence of `<Stack />`, the deserializer will encounter an unknown node. Workaround in case you are missing this attribute, subscribe to `UnknownElement`:

```
var fooSrlz = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Foo), new XmlRootAttribute { ElementName = "Foo", IsNullable = true} );
var foosMissedByDeserializer = new List<CData.Foo>();
srlz.UnknownElement += (/*object*/ sender, /*XmlElementEventArgs  */ e) => {
    using (TextReader tr = new StringReader(e.Element.OuterXml)) {
      var foo = (CData.Foo)fooSrlz.Deserialize(tr);
      foosMissedByDeserializer.Add (foo);
    } };
```

Merge the deserialization result with the *foosMissedByDeserializer* above.